# Asp.Net : How to provide email preview for the different email providers

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net application I need to show the email preview of created email, like with gmail the email will display some different formatting & with hotmail it will some different formatting...

So, How to provide email preview for the different email providers like gmail, hotmail rediffmail etc...

Is their any tool with which I can render in my application?

Comment: I've never heard of such a scheme. It sounds quite involved and error prone. What if the relevant system changed their email rendering strategies? And it also depends on if images are loaded, etc. Any reason you need to do this? Can't you just generate a correctly-formed HTML email?

Comment: Good question, would be very useful as along with different browsers they all have their own small differences

Comment: No silky, as per requirement I need to display email previews not html preview of the mail 
For eg. My observation :- 
Consider something as simple as the “p” tag used to define paragraphs in HTML text. Gmail separates the paragraphs nicely but 
Yahoo! Mail doesn’t.... It happens due to "Lack of email standard" 
please refer : - http://www.smartinsights.com/blog/email-marketing/email-preview-tools/

Answer (score 0):

How about an external service such as Litmus App (http://litmusapp.com/)?  They have an API which may also be of some use.

Comment: Hi Sam, 
Thanks a lot for your time.
 Yes this is what I was looking for.
 But From My application I can't use this as I want to design & send the millions of mails & It will be costly in my case.

I am looking for the any algorithm to generate the 5 to 6 previews 
Or Any third party freeware tool which I can include in the application.
:)

Comment: Hmm if you manage to find/create such a solution then I think there is a big market for it, but as there are a number of paid for services already out there I suspect that no such free service currently exists.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the only truly reliable means of doing this (and the way we use for in-house QA at the ad agency where I do my day-job) is to have a handful of test email accounts (one on Hotmail, one on Yahoo!, one on Gmail etc) and send a test email to each.

You can mock them up, but they won't be 100% reliable, particularly if you need to deal with batshitcrazy clients like Lotus Notes. Litmus looks like a good second-best.

If you *really* need to do the preview within your app and can't call out to an API, the best you can realistically manage is to inspect the HTML and CSS of each client (Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo! etc) and generate an HTML preview inside their page chrome and stylesheet. But I'd strongly recommend against that — it'd be a lot of work and would need constant checking and updating.

Your best bet genuinely is the dull and tedious method of sending it to a test account on each provider. Sorry.